# GMV can't detect AAMVA driver license

Tags: ios, objective-c, android-vision

I'm using [Barcode API](https://developers.google.com/vision/ios/barcodes-overview) from Google Mobile Vision GMV to scan AAMVA driver license type.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSDictionary *options = @{
    GMVDetectorBarcodeFormats : @(GMVDetectorBarcodeFormatQRCode | GMVDetectorBarcodeFormatPDF417)
  };

  // Initialize a barcode detector.
  self.barcodeDetector = [GMVDetector detectorOfType:GMVDetectorTypeBarcode options:options];
}
```

The app now detects PDF417 types but not Driver licenses.

What I'm missing ?

Comment: Even the sample code provided can't read driver licence which could be read on Android Sample.

Comment: I added GMVDetectorBarcodeValueFormatDriversLicense in options. But still it's not working

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to be caused by the capture session preset.
I found the solution under Google Mobile Vision's GitHub issues:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Set up default camera settings.
  self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
  self.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
```

https://github.com/googlesamples/ios-vision/issues/6